# how to save images directly to a folder on a vps server

Tags: php

i'm using this function

`@imagepng($image, 'http://103.129.223.xx/face/' .$player->getName().'.png');`

but return this message on console

**imagepng(http://103.129.223.xx/face/alair069.png): failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections**

Comment: You need to use the right protocol to write a file remotely. HTTP is not the right protocol.

Comment: Could you give me an example the right way?

Comment: It depends on your VPS. The only thing I know for sure is that PHP doesn't let you do it via HTTP ever, regardless of the VPS's configuration.